# AJAX call url does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, call

I am designing a webpage to play and control an IP camera that can move up/down, zoom in/out, etc. To make those movements we have to call a url. As I am playing the content from the webcam, I have to do these calls asynchronously. I have tried to do it with AJAX but there is no result.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#up").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://192.168.1.101:88/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=ptzMoveUp&usr=admin&pwd=", 
            success: function(result){
                $("#div1").html('Moving UP');
            }
        });
     });
 });
</script>

...

<button id="up" class="arrow" type="button"><b>UP</b></button>
...
<div id="div1"><h2>This text doesn't change</h2></div>
```

Comment: `http://192.168.1...`

Comment: try prefix with `http://` or `https://` or just `//`

Comment: Did you take any mistake on console?

Comment: I forgot the http in the question, but is in my code and it still does not work

Comment: according my servers , connecting to IP addresses that start with 192 require Virtual Private Network (VPN) and why can't you use domain name instead of IP address ?

Comment: @JSantosh - don't throw him a curveball, DNS is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery selector is wrong. Change:

`$(".up").click(function(){....`

(`.` implies `up` is a class)

to:

`$("#up").click(function(){....`

(`#` implies `up` is an id)

**Further reading on jQuery selectors:**

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it still does not work. I know that # is for id but I tried other ways to fix it and forgot to change it again when posting the question

Comment: Ok, well in that case - familiarise yourself with developer tools, monitor the requests made (the 'network' tab) and check whether the ajax call is even being made. If it is - what is the response? It could be that the server is returning an error (if it's even being reached). In which case, you don't have an 'error' handler - so you would never know.

Comment: The only other possibility, is that the event handler hasn't been wired up. This can happen when your button element has been created AFTER the event handler has been declared. Quite often the case when using update panels/injecting elements with ajax. Although it's rarer than a bad response from a server.

Comment: That means your call is unable to reach the server, and thus ends in timing out. So this is more like a server issue (if you are sure your url is valid) or a proxy's one.